# How to do a generic order

Tags: r

I have a database as a data frame and I would like to order all columns, but keeping relations between elements.
For example, if I do the following:

```
> DF
   A B   C D
1 11 2 432 4
2 11 3 432 4
3 13 4 241 5
4 42 5   2 3
5 51 5 332 2
6 51 5 332 1
7 51 5 332 1
> DF=DF[order(A,B,C,D),]
> DF
   A B   C D
1 11 2 432 4
2 11 3 432 4
3 13 4 241 5
4 42 5   2 3
6 51 5 332 1
7 51 5 332 1
5 51 5 332 2
```

Ok, this is what I wanted (pay atention to the last two rows), but I would like to have a generic solution, independent of the number of columns. I have tried the following, but it does not work.

```
> DF=DF[order(colnames(DF)),]
> DF
   A B   C D
1 11 2 432 4
2 11 3 432 4
3 13 4 241 5
4 42 5   2 3
```

I would be grateful if someone could help me with this little issue. Regards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `do.call` with `order` for ordering on all the columns of a dataset

```
DF[do.call(order, DF),]
```

---

If we use `tidyverse`, there is `arrange_at` that will take column names

```
library(dplyr)
DF %>%
    arrange_at(vars(names(.)))
    #or as @Sotos commented
    #arrange_all()
    #or
    #arrange(!!! rlang::syms(names(.)))
#   A B   C D
#1 11 2 432 4
#2 11 3 432 4
#3 13 4 241 5
#4 42 5   2 3
#5 51 5 332 1
#6 51 5 332 1
#7 51 5 332 2
```

Comment: Great! Thank you very much, akrun. I have another question in relation to the package sqldf, I was wondering if you could help me with this another matter. Question: how to keep initial row order.

Comment: @Citizen  you didn't mention about the `sqldf` part in the question.  It is not clear from your comment what you expect

Comment: @akrun : this is second time today i realised answer is already posted by you when i was still editing mine :)

Comment: It is another question. I asked the question yesterday. The title is: how to keep initial row order.

Comment: There is also `arrange_all()` in `dplyr`, so just `DF %>% arrange_all()` should do it

Comment: akrun, Sotos Thank you very much for your help

Comment: @Citizen I checked your other question about sqldf.  Added the solution there